# Making an Emacs Derived Mode

Tags: emacs, major-mode

Have been using modus-vivendi theme to which I add a bold font for everything for some time.

I would like to introduce a special customisation for comments, using normal weight, and having a keybinding that changes the contrast ratio between the comment colour and the background.

Had started writing a minor mode, but some have suggested the use of a derived mode, as the appropriate way to customise comments as described. Any examples I can use?

In the elisp manual I found define-derived-mode. As the new customisotion is for comments, I would surmise that a closely related mode to inherit would be prog-mode.

But I have no experience on how to go about successfully making a derived mode.

```
(defvar richkov-annotation-contrast 2
  "Sets the colour contrast (against background) for comments.")

(defvar richkov-annotation-chroma

  ;; Using two Association Lists, each compased of a Chroma Intensity
  ;; Key (low, mid, high) associated with an RGB Hex-Code.  Emacs
  ;; Minibuffer Command `M-x list-colors-display' lists colour names
  ;; and hex-codes.
  
  '( (dark .  ((low  . "#8300E0")     ; indigo (Blu:63% Red:37% Grn:0%)
               (mid  . "#AA33FF")     ; indigo (Blu:54% Red:36% Grn:11%)
               (high . "#C370FF")))   ; indigo (Blu:45% Red:35% Grn:20%)

     (light . ((low  . "#C16BFF")     ; indigo (Blu:46% Red:35% Grn:19%)
               (mid  . "#AA33FF")     ; indigo (Blu:54% Red:36% Grn:11%)
               (high . "#8000DB"))) ) ; indigo (Blu:63% Red:37% Grn:0%)

  "Colour contrast for comments, indigo on dark and light background.")

(defun richkov-annotation-font-weight ()
  "Use normal weight typeface for comments."
  (set-face-attribute 'font-lock-comment-face nil :weight 'normal))

(princ "Weight: ")
(princ (face-attribute 'default :weight))

(defun richkov-annotation-typeface (chroma)
  "Set the foreground colour for comments.

CHROMA  Intensity Key used for setting colour of comments ."

  (message "richkov-annotation-typeface ")
  (let* ( (colors richkov-annotation-chroma)

          (levels
       (alist-get (frame-parameter nil 'background-mode) colors)) )
    
    ;; make comment colour change buffer-local
    (face-remap-add-relative 'font-lock-comment-face
       `(:foreground ,(alist-get chroma levels)))

    (message "richkov-annotation: %s contrast" chroma)) )

(defun richkov-annotation-sweep ()
   "Cycles through the colour chroma for comments.
Colours are determined by `richkov-annotation'."
   (interactive)

   (pcase richkov-annotation-contrast
     (1
        (richkov-annotation-typeface 'low)
        (setq richkov-annotation-contrast 2))
     (2
        (richkov-annotation-typeface 'mid)
        (setq richkov-annotation-contrast 3))
     (_
        (richkov-annotation-typeface 'high)
        (setq richkov-annotation-contrast 1)) ))

(defun richkov-annotation-low-contrast ()
  (when richkov-minor-mode
    (richkov-annotation-typeface 'low)))

(defun richkov-annotation-keytrigger ()
  "Key trigger for rapid execution of richkov commands"
  (interactive)
  (global-set-key (kbd "H-;") #'richkov-annotation-sweep))

(defun richkov-annotation-tools ()
  "Aggregates annotation tools for comments."
  (richkov-annotation-font-weight)
  (richkov-annotation-low-contrast)
  (richkov-annotation-keytrigger))

;;;###autoload
(define-minor-mode richkov-minor-mode
  "Colour Brace Marks according to their depth." 
  :lighter "richkov"  ; indicator in mode-line
  
  (font-lock-remove-keywords nil richkov-font-lock)
  (set-face-attribute 'font-lock-comment-face nil
     :weight (face-attribute 'default :weight))

  (when richkov-minor-mode
    (font-lock-add-keywords nil richkov-font-lock 'append)
    (set (make-local-variable 'jit-lock-contextually) t)
    (richkov-annotation-tools))
  
  (when font-lock-mode
    (if (fboundp 'font-lock-flush)
        (font-lock-flush)
      (with-no-warnings (font-lock-fontify-buffer)) )) )

;;;###autoload
(defun richkov-minor-mode-enable ()
  "Enable `richkov-minor-mode'."
  (richkov-minor-mode 1))

;;;###autoload
(defun richkov-minor-mode-disable ()
  "Disable `richkov-minor-mode'."
  (richkov-minor-mode 0))
```

Comment: I could do it over prog-mode.  Stefan does not suggest using a minor-mode for things that are usually handled by a theme customisation.

Comment: Yes, I was doing the same myself, a minor-mode for customisation of comments.  I want to implement a number of methodologies, then make a comparison.  This would help in making an implementation that is more convenient to modify in future.  Would you join me in the effort, as I do not want things to be based solely on my opinion.

Comment: I would like to use the comment customisations for programming languages (and for org-mode and texinfo-mode where programming type comments can be inserted).

Comment: What's the question? Are you asking how to create a major mode that's derived from another? I don't think so, as you show that you've tried that. If you have a *specific* question about what you tried, e.g., something that didn't work, please ask that. As it stands now, the question is too broad/unclear.

Comment: The question:  What is the most appropriate way to implement comment customisation?  Using a minor-mode, defining a derived mode from a major-mode, or use a customisation theme?

Comment: *"the most appropriate way"* encourages opinion-based answers. Should be closed, IMO.

Comment: I want to validate those opinions.